# How to directly read/write stored computer data through code

Tags: c#, memory-management, binary

Whenever I've googled how to do it, no matter what I try I get answers on how to install new hard drives, RAM etc. or information on how hard drives and RAM work.

Let's say I am using C#, how would I attempt to directly change the computer's saved data, such as changing directly changing the binary.

I may be confusing in this question so I'll give an example of what I -think- is a program doing this. AVG has a 'data shredder' function that I believe makes it impossible to recover a deleted file, as I assume it changes the binary (or something) to random values on the allocated face the file was located. How would I achieve this in C# (or any other language for that matter)

Similarly, how does AVG move data to 'defragment'? I assume it reads and writes the data to the 'front' of the disk so it's faster to read it.

I hope I've made myself clear, and I'm thinking it depends on the OS as well.

Comment: Try taking the CS50 class from Harvard on edX... It will cover the details about what a file actually is, how 'shredding' and data recovery actually work. Then you'll be better positioned to approach what you want to do.

Comment: Now I've been downvoted with no explanation. Whoever did this, please explain how my question '...does not show any research effort; ... is unclear or not useful'. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidAnderton I'll have a look, is there any specific words for what I'd describing? I cannot find one.

Comment: Wasn't me, I think the question doesn't have the understanding of the way memory and file storage work - but that's why you asked.  I do recommend taking that course. File systems can be pretty dry to learn about otherwise

Comment: Ok so to explain one thing briefly... When you delete a file usually you do not delete the data of that file. You basically just lose your link to it and declare the space free to use.  AVG would write new random data over where your file was to ensure it can only be recovered by someone sifting through your 'free' space looking for lost files

Comment: @DavidAnderton Yes I know that fully, that is the reason you can recover data shortly after the file has been set as 'deleted', I want to know how to access the raw disk data directly. Of course we can't really converse via comments, but if someone reads these comments perhaps they will understand better of what my question was meant to want.

Comment: I think the answer below from James deals with this. It can't natively be done in C# too many protections to prevent you from  destroying the filesystem by mistake. Try using C if you want to get into the deep end, but beware you can mess things up royally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about is access to the raw disk sectors.  C# doesn't have access at that level without using a technique called PInvoke, which is very advanced.  Such access requires detailed knowledge of the various disk layout structures such as NTFS and FAT32, as well as partitioning schemes such as GPT.  Without that knowledge you will very likely corrupt the drive you're attempting to operate on, causing it to not be able to be read by the operating system.

Comment: Okay, you've given me some jargon I can actually use to google, but I'm not sure it's the correct answer yet as I don't -understand- your answer fully. I will at least up vote your answer for now.

Answer (score 2):

For performance reasons most modern operating systems do not wipe the data on hard drives, but just mark space occupied by deleted files as available for new data write instead. Thus it is possible sometimes to remove this mark and gain access to the deleted data. To securely wipe the data it must be overwritten. So, in C# you can open a file for read-write and overwrite it with random binary data, then close the file and flush the buffer on disk. This operation can be repeated a few times to make sure the data is lost. This is relevant for FAT16/32 file system on spindle hard drive. With most modern storage devices there is no universal solution.

For further advice please have a look at these:

- [Disk Storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_storage)
- [File System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system)
- [Data Erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_erasure)
- [Defragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defragmentation)

Comment: You've also helped me to find some more references, however it seems I might not be able to get an answer as people are not understanding exactly what I want. Perhaps another more extensive search is in order.

Comment: I'm not sure this would necessarily write to the same memory that the file was read from...

Comment: For compressed/encrypted/sparse files overwriting in situ will fail as NTFS will always write to space it allocates anew for such files.

Comment: @Alex K. Absolutely. There is also no guarantee of overwriting for any storage device with own integrated logic, SAS / NAS etc. I am afraid there can be no universal C# solution. So I have answered the question on very basic level with some links for further reading.